# Drag and Drop Zone opening file instead of uploading to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have a file upload zone, one that let's you choose the file while the other is a drag and drop file upload zone.

Choosing file and clicking submit works perfectly fine. 
The drag and drop zone however opens/downloads the file instead of uploading.

I think my PHP code is correct, because the file is getting correctly uploaded to server on choosing and uploading.

This is the JQuery code where I think there's a possible error.

```
+ function($) {
    'use strict';

    // UPLOAD CLASS DEFINITION
    // ======================

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
    var uploadForm = document.getElementById('js-upload-form');

    var startUpload = function(files) {
        console.log(files)
    }

    uploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        var uploadFiles = document.getElementById('js-upload-files').files;
        e.preventDefault()

        startUpload(uploadFiles)
    })

    dropZone.ondrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'upload-drop-zone';

        startUpload(e.dataTransfer.items)
    }

    dropZone.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-drop-zone drop';
        return false;
    }

    dropZone.ondragleave = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-drop-zone';
        return false;
    }

}(jQuery);
```

Here's the HTML for a better reference:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Upload CSV File</strong> <small>Insert Leads to MongoDB</small></div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <!-- Standard Form -->
          <h4>Select files from your computer</h4>
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="js-upload-form">
            <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="js-upload-files">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="js-upload-submit">Upload files</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <!-- Drop Zone -->
          <h4>Or drag and drop files below</h4>
          <div class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone">
            Just drag and drop files here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the drag and drop zone to upload the file to server as well instead of opening.

Comment: [It seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/gpzsrhv7/1/). However, note that the drop zone is quite small; it's only the area of the "Just drag and drop files here" text. Are you sure you're dropping the file directly onto that area? If so, have you included the jQuery library? I notice that jQuery is not necessary for the drag-and-drop code you've shown. But the code will not execute unless the library is present because the `jQuery` variable will not be defined.

Comment: Don't worry about the area, they are maintained well in the CSS.
I have included the jQuery library, otherwise the choose and upload won't work either.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any code for that. Is it not working for you in my JSFiddle? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It worked in your JSFiddle, gotta check what's the issue in my code.

Comment: It might be worth checking the browser console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do.